# Flutter release app crashing and showing gray screen

Tags: flutter

I am getting a crash on some android devices when running my Flutter app.

I have been able to debug a release version of the app and this is the only debug output:

```
W/FlutterJNI(27448): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(27448): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than once
W/FlutterJNI(27448): FlutterJNI.init called more than once
```

I don´t know where should I begin to look for the reason of the issue.

The device is showing a gray screen and stops working.

Comment: Are you using Firebase in your app?

Comment: you can try ErrorWidget to handle this error. i.e : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ErrorWidget-class.html

Comment: how are you handling error in your app, you can start from there.

Comment: @EricAig, yes I am

Comment: Has this been solved...I see the answer is marked as accepted? Those are warnings and I wouldn't expect them to cause a crash. They occur because you are initializing firebase messaging more than once. Don't think they relate to your crash at all.

Comment: @GrahamD, you are right, I have solved the issue changing firebase messaging declarations only once

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you create the `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`, annotate it with `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` like this:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

}
```

The reason is explained here:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging/example/lib/main.dart#L46

Comment: it is not solved after adding the line @pragma('vm:entry-point')